# QT: Form validation with inter-fields rules

Tags: c++, qt

1. I would like to dynamically build a form to edit a set of properties (say from a xml file or so).
2. On top of that, I would like to perform validation for each property (mandatory values/optional values) with a set of rules (ideally also dynamically loaded).
   These rules could be associated to a single field (allowed values, range, ...) but could also link several fields (conditional validation).
3. I would like to be able to save the results "on the fly" (as soon as a field loses focus).

Does someone have a good lead to get me started?
Here is what I found so far:

1. I could start from the Qt property browser framework for the dynamic form generation. I could extend this framework to suit my needs.
2. Regarding the validation, I read about QValidator which seems to be a good start. However, I couldn't find anything involving several fields (cross-parameter validation)
3. The QSettings framework does this auto-save feature quite nicely and I guess I could reuse that.

I just wanted to be sure I am not missing some existing framework to deal with my goals since
it seems like a relatively standard thing to do.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the fields of the form are *fixed*. Then you could use a shared instance of a  `QValidator`to validate the text in all the fields by running your validaton over a *list* /*dictionary* /*map* containing pointers to the fields. The *list*/*dictionary*/*map* will have to by dynamically populated and cleared, and a pointer to it hard-coded inside  `QValidate::validate`. And if `QValidator` sharing is not allowed you will have to create individual ones and execute your cross-field validation.

Alternatively, you could use *Qt's Signal-Slot* mechanism to implement your validation whenever the text in your field is changed.

I had no idea of QSetting, and would have used the very same *signal-slot* mechanism to do the autosave.